# Real Time facial recognition software that can capture mouth and eyes

Tags: video, camera, facial-recognition

I'm looking for a facial recognition software that can capture in real time the eyes and the mouth of a person from a camera input. The idea is to to be able to then crop and put the eyes and mouth on another video output.

Preference for free software but will consider anything.

The software will need to run on both IOS and Android.

So far, my solution is to use the open source C library [flandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/index.php)/[clandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/clandmark/index.php?page=documentation) and do some custom coding but I'd rather not. It looks simple enough and is free but the documentation is weak.

Otherwise, I've also looked into OpenCV and it also looks good but again, the documentation looks weak.

There's also openface that looked really user friendly but it doesn't support smartphone CPU architecture.

*edited based on comments

Comment: Did you see that it is replaced by [clandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/clandmark/)?

Comment: @Izzy It needs to run on IOS and Android. 'This' was a C open source library called clandmark. What I like is it's in C so I'm guessing it shouldn't be a problem porting it to IOS and Android and integrating it into an app. I'm also looking into OpenCV right now which seems like a more feature rich library that does similar things. I'd really like something super easy to use though...

Comment: A little dated and in python but https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/ will give you a good starting point for OpenCV.